# macos switching application between multiple displays

Tags: macos

I am coming in from a windows background where I used to work with multiple displays.  One of the most frequently used shortcuts on Windows was win+left or win+right to move windows between multiple displays.  Is there a similar shortcut on macos.  I have seen some documentation on installing third party apps and then configuring them, but I would prefer something native on macos, since third party apps could slow down the system.

Comment: Voting to close as this has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag and drop the window to the display on left or right.

Also, take a look [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another)